# Active Record syntax explanation - beginner

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm working on learning ruby/rails at the moment - The book i'm reading has had a tendency to skip over bits of new syntax. In particular, this bit;

```
person = Person.find(:first, :conditions => ["name = ?", "Mikey"])
```

From what I can tell this method takes a symbol as its first argument and what looks like a one-item hash with a symbol/array key/value. Is this correct and if so, why am I suddenly able to specify a hash without curly braces { } in this context?

Comment: You might want to go one step closer to the `NEW` Active Record syntax, now It will be a little different from that like:  `person = Person.where('name = ?','Mokey').first` -> http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

Comment: @Mr_Nizzle: in this particular case: `person = Person.where(:name => "Mikey").first`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Ruby method parameters, any key=>value pairs that are placed after normal arguments, but before a block, are bundled into a single hash.  So if you called

```
my_method("hello", :something=>"yo!", :another_thing=>"bah!")
```

that means that `my_method` is being passed two arguments, a string ("hello"), and a hash ({:something=>"yo!", :another_thing=>"bah!"}).

Among other reasons, this prevents confusion between curly braces indicating a hash parameter, and curly braces indicating a block.  It also makes a convenient way to simulate "named parameters", which otherwise don't exist in Ruby.

Comment: As an additional note, the free-form hash argument must be the last argument or you will have to put in explicit braces. `foo(:a => 'b')` is fine, but `foo(:a => 'b', x)` is not and has to be `foo({ :a => 'b' }, x)` instead. Generally most interfaces define the argument hash last for this reason.

Comment: Indeed -- that's what I meant to convey by "after normal arguments".